# Best way to create a DTO that reflects many to many releation using REST api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this pseudo model to illustrate the idea

```
class Author
{ 
   List<authorbook> AuthorBooks{get;set;} 
}

class Book
{ 
   List<authorbook> AuthorBooks{get;set;} 
}

class AuthorBook
{
   Author Author {get;set;} 
   Book Book {get;set;} 
   bool IsRequired{get;set;} //An extrafield on the relation
}
```

Which is the best approach when you need to return on WebApi the book that you created after calling to your BookController for CreatBookForAuthor?

You should receive in someway the IsRequired field to save it as an extra value on the middle table, now, after you establish the relation which is the best approach to let the user know that a specific Boolean value was assigned to that an Author with IsRequired value on true?

How should look the BookDto to return to maintain a RESTFUL approach? Please use the same scenario to illustrate an answer

Answer (score 0):

The data model doesn't need to exactly match the database schema.

Generally you need to break the hierarchy by having the book DTO contain `AuthorInfo` (`Name`, `ID`) instead of the whole `Author` object, and vice-versa, author DTO should have `BookInfo` objects (`ISBN`, `title`, `publicationDate`, and maybe a set of `AuthorInfo`)

I.e. distinguish between `Author` (everything you know about the author) and `AuthorInfo` (the bit of information you want to include when referencing the author).

```
/// <summary>
/// The information about a book which is included with an Author
/// </summary>
class AuthorBookInfo
{
    // to get the full Book object if needed
    public string Id; 
    // Extra information about the relation (join table)
    public AuthorRole Role; // Editor, Author, Contributor, etc.
    // Now extra information from book to reduce the need to retrieve the book object
    public string Title;
    public string ISBN;
    public DateTime PublicationDate;
}


class Author {
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<AuthorBookInfo> Books;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    public string ShortBiography;

}

class AuthorInfo
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
}

class Book {
    public string Id; // to get the full Book object if needed
    public string Title;
    public string ISBN;
    public DateTime PublicationDate;
    public List<AuthorInfo> Authors;
    public PublisherInfo Publisher;
    public string PublicationLanguage;
    public List<BookInfo> Translations;
}
```

The main requirement is to include the `Id`, so full details of the related objects can be retrieved in a separate call.

The secondary goal is to include just enough of the most commonly-needed extra information so that the second call is not needed most of the time.

Comment: my question is more how to represent correctly a model for that scenario

Comment: @Heinrich "How should look the BookDto to return to maintain a RESTFUL approach" "Best way to create a dto that reflects a many to many relation using rest api".